# Error number: 33: SessionNotCreatedError session not created exception from unknown error while trying to simulate chrome browser using SeleniumBasic

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using the COM interface provided by Internet Explorer but, since some sites have now moved on and don't support IE, I have been looking to substitute this with `SeleniumBasic`.

As this is completely new to me, I'm at the very basic level - I've downloaded the 
Selenium Type Library (I've downloaded the [Selenium library reference from Github](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases), and referenced is in the module).

I've put in a very basic bit of code to test it out but I'm getting the following error:

Error number: 33
Error description:

> SessionNotCreatedError session not created exception from unknown
>   error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':
>   {"auxData":{"frameId":"AE85B634088DDFB4B8E7D65A145ADA0F","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>   (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0
>   x86_64)

The code is;

```
Sub TestCode()
Dim driver as New Selenium.Chrome

driver.get "www.Google.com" 

End Sub
```

I've tried this with firefox and Edge browsers too but am getting the same issues - any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
SessionNotCreatedError session not created exception from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"AE85B634088DDFB4B8E7D65A145ADA0F","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"} 
 (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100) 
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.21*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.21*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v46-50**

- You are using *chrome=69.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.21* and the *Chrome Browser v69.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Update A

As per [florentbr/SeleniumBasic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) the last version of **SeleniumBasic** (*A Selenium based browser automation framework for VB.Net, Visual Basic Applications and VBScript*) seems to be **Release v2.0.9.0** only.

As per the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/commit/8a2cde358d2bc06e3014aca2c8d427bc61188a1b) of **Release v2.0.9.0** the underlying components are:

- **Firefox driver version 2.52.0**
- **IE driver version 2.52.1**

---

### Update B

If you intend to use *GeckoDriver* with *Firefox* you can following the matrix below:

[image: geckodriver-firefox]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've downloaded the Selenium `.jar` file but I can't figure out to include this in my reference library - can you give me a bit of a steer? Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I am afraid as I work with Java/Python/NodeJS bindings only but not Basic/vba. The issue was quite clear and evident so tried to help you out. Wait for @QHarr to have a look at this counter question.

Comment: @QHarr I'm sorry to dragging you into this but would you be able to help here? I did download the Selenium wrapper but it was the 2.9 version which doesn't work for me - is there a 3.14 version of VBA (I can't find it anywhere!!)?

Comment: Checkout the update within my answer, may be you will be able to pull out something useful.

Comment: Thanks, that was my suspicion - So really what I would need to do is downgrade a browser and then use that (probably Firefox, which is throwing up the same error)?

Comment: Checkout the update within my answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I do appreciate you efforts but the oldest version Selenium listed is 3.4 whereas the newest version available to me (for VBA) is 2.9. I was hopeful for this beforehand but I'm starting to think I'm out of my depth! Are you aware of any other alternatives to Selenium?

Comment: Don't loose your attention. Configuration is a one time effort. I am sure you are close to a working configuration. If you are stuck some where else feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. @Florent B. (SeleniumBasic creator) is active here as well and would be able to guide you in a moment. Added some more update within my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've just downgraded my chrome to v49 and only use the ChromeDriver. I appreciate your patience with me!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see any of these messages as I hadn't interacted with the thread. But actually swung by looking for a similar post and came across this. Great answer @DebanjanB + . Do you mind adding in the Chrome info to update A (or was that missing from any available documentation?  - it used to be you couldn't use FF > than v.46.0.1. but Chrome you were ok so long as binary went with Chrome version. I would like to be able to use this as a dupe target (i.e. send people here)