# Run-time error 33 - SessionNotCreatedError

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

Getting this error when attempting to use the Selenium Type Library to launch Chrome:

[image: img1]

My Chrome version is 93, so not sure why these are incompatible.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WD As WebDriver

Public Sub Update_Numbers()
        
    Set WD = New ChromeDriver
        
    With WD
        .Start "Chrome" ' error here
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691299/error-number-33-sessionnotcreatederror-session-not-created-exception-from-unkn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message your Chrome version is `113.0.5672.93` and not `93`.

You can confirm that by opening Chrome, clicking on the three dots `⋮` in the top right corner and in the dropdown on `Help` -> `About Google Chrome`. I assume that this will indeed show you current Chrome version to be `113.0.5672.93`.

Since your installed webdriver is only compatible with Chrome version 93 (A very outdated version from August 2021) you will need to update your `ChromeDriver`.

You can do that by:

- Navigating to the ChromeDriver download page: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- Finding the appropriate release for your version of Chrome, in your case [*ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=113.0.5672.63/)
- Downloading the appropriate driver for your environment, assuming you are running windows, from this [download link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/113.0.5672.63/chromedriver_win32.zip)
- Unpack the downloaded .zip file, it should contain a file called *chromedriver.exe*
- Navigate to your SeleniumBasic install directory, probably *%LOCALAPPDATA%\SeleniumBasic\* and replace the existing *chromedriver.exe* file in this directory with the new *chromedriver.exe* file you just downloaded.

Comment: Ahh, I just assumed that the last 2 digits of that Chrome version string was my "version", not the whole string - that was my issue. Downloaded the new ChromeDriver for my exact version and it works like a charm. Thanks.