# Open a login website via google chrome Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error, geturl

I'm trying to open a website thats need username and password to login Via Google Chrome with Excel. I already selected "Selenium Type Library" reference.When i run my codes (As below), i get an Run-time error 33.
Thank you in advance for your help

```
Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
    Dim bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://auto.lotus.ir/faces/pages/security/login.xhtml?  ignoreAutoLogin=true&message=enableAutoLogin"
    username = "lili"
    password = "123456"
    bot.Get URL
    bot.FindElementByName("j_username").SendKeys username
    bot.FindElementByName("j_password").SendKeys password
    bot.FindElementById("Submit").Click
    bot.Quit


    End Sub
```

Comment: [Install steps for Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps)

Comment: Your URL `auto.lotus.ir ... ` may have a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

That could be incompatibility between driver and webbrowser. Did you search for "vba error 33"

[Error number: 33: SessionNotCreatedError session not created exception from unknown error while trying to simulate chrome browser using SeleniumBasic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691299/error-number-33-sessionnotcreatederror-session-not-created-exception-from-unkn)

[Using Google Chrome in Selenium VBA (Installation Steps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps)